# How many laptops onboard ISS?

Tags: iss, computer

About how many laptops are there on board the ISS? I saw the header image in this article:
https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/11/science/scott-mark-kelly-twins-space-nasa.html?partner=rss&emc=rss
and spotted three, maybe a fourth laptop, all in the cupola. I have seen laptops mounted at several places within one lab of the ISS. How many laptops would there be in the whole station?

Do astronauts need/use their own "personal" device(s), or do they (literally) float from one device to the next? Do they have roaming profiles that maintain their schedules/alarms for them? Do they have to keep "logging off" their peers who forget to do it themselves?

Comment: See https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2016/05/14/what-kind-of-laptops-are-on-the-iss/#311b96472950

Comment: Possibly related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/43562/why-so-many-laptops-on-the-iss